# Usage of "giddy" and "dizzy"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

I pinged a friend saying that *I am feeling giddy and dizzy*. She mistook me for being happy and thought I was expressing a positive feeling, while I was actually feeling sick and disoriented. Do we use the words *giddy* and *dizzy* to express happiness or excitement?

Answer (score 3):

One commonly used meaning of *[giddy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/giddy)* is *frivolous* or *impulsive*; the phrase *giddy with excitement* uses this meaning.  It's not exactly the same as happiness, but it can mean *overwhelmingly excited*.  However, *[dizzy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dizzy)* is not generally used to mean *excited*, though excitement can have that effect.  Other than its main meaning of *having a sensation of whirling and a tendency to fall*, it has more of a connotation of *thoughtless* or *confused*.

If I had received the message, I would have come to the conclusion that you were not feeling well, since you used the word *dizzy*.  If you had said "I am feeling giddy and dizzy *with excitement*", then I would have known you were describing the extent of your excitement, rather than the state of your health.  And if you had said "I am feeling giddy", I would probably have pinged you back asking in what way you felt giddy—with excitement, or with disorientation.  So if you aren't feeling well, *dizzy* is a better word to use than *giddy*, since *giddy* can also mean *excited*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If someone else had pinged me saying that he/she felt giddy and dizzy i would have concluded that he/she was ill. Perhaps, a sudden ping like this would confuse the person on the other end.

Comment: However, is giddy and dizzy colloquially used to express a state of excitement?

Comment: I did mention in my answer that by itself, *giddy* does, but *dizzy* doesn't really.

Answer (score 1):

Dizzy was very appropriate, but (as a native english speaker in America) I have never heard giddy used in that sense.  To me, giddy always means overwhelmingly excited.

If you want to emphasize that you feel unwell, avoid saying "giddy."

Comment: When I looked up _giddy_ in the dictionary, I found that it means "dizzy" and "unsteady". Still, Noah is right; I've also usually heard the word used colloquially in a more positive sense: _the young lovers were giddy with excitement_. If I wanted to say that I was feeling ill, I would have probably gone for _woozy and dizzy_. Still, the fault probably lies on us hearers; when I looked up the word _giddy_ in dictionaries and corpuses, I found no compelling reason to always associate it with something positive – in fact, quite the opposite.

Comment: Descriptive linguists would tell you that lanuage is constantly evolving and the hearers have a better understanding than the dictionaries ever could. :)

Comment: That's one side of the coin, for sure. On the other, I'm always very hesitant to say, "I'm right; it's the _dictionary_ that's wrong!"  This wasn't the first time I've learned that a word was defined differently than I had expected, and I doubt it'll be the last.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. My first impression was that the word pattern was similar to some lines from a once very popular song in *West Side Story* that go, "I feel pretty and witty and gay" / "I feel **dizzy**/ I feel sunny/ I feel fizzy and funny and fine" etc. There is a parody at kurtfstone.com that changes it to: "I feel nifty/ I feel witty and **giddy** and gay. David Sederis titled one of his books "Me Talk Pretty One Day" which also might be a nod to the song in the musical.